Gamma function as infinite product
Let´s consider the Gamma function expression due to Euler and Gauss:
$$\Gamma(z) = \frac{1}{ze^{\gamma}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+\frac{z}{n})e^{\frac{-z}{n}}}  $$

I am interested in showing that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})e^{\frac{-1}{n}}$ converges to $e^{-\gamma}.$
Having already proved $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z), \forall z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0,-1,-2,...\}$ and the factorial expression $\Gamma(n+1)=n! \,(n\geq 0)$ as well, how can I show $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt\pi?$
Can I derive from the expression above that $\Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$ in $Re(z)>0?$
How can I calculate the residual at $z=-n$ without using the factorial expression?


Item (1) follows from the expression and $\Gamma(1)=1$. With respect to item (4) $$\text{res}(\Gamma(z),{z,-n})=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(n+1)},,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}\land n\ge 0\tag{1}$$ and $$\text{res}\left(\Gamma(z), x^{-z},{z,-n}\right)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!},  x^n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(n+1)}, x^n,,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}\land n\ge 0\tag{2}$$ where formula (2) is related to item (3) via the residue formula $$e^{-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}, x^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(n+1)}, x^n,.\tag{3}$$

In fact, I was interested in proving item (1) in order to get the expression for Gamma at 1.

List of indications :

Set $z=1$, put the product in exponential form :
$$\exp ( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) - \frac{1}{n})$$
and use $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} = \ln(N) + \gamma + o(1)$ to get its value.

2 and 4. Since you proved the formulas $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$ and $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$, you can show that :
$$\Gamma(1-z) \Gamma(z) = -z\Gamma(-z) \Gamma(z) = ( z \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}) )^{-1} = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$$
From there you can get both the value at $z = \frac{1}{2}$ and the residuals at $z=-n$

Denoting $f(z)$ the right hand side, show that $f$ verifies $f(z+1)=zf(z)$. Then, show that $f$ can be continued on all the complex plane (except zero and negative integers) by the meromorphic function :
$$F(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(z+n)} + \int_1^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$$
(separate the $\int_0^1$ part from the rest and expand $e^{-t}$ in a power series)

From the theorem of analytic continuation, deduce the formula $F(z+1) = zF(z)$
Then define $g(z) := \frac{\Gamma(z)}{F(z)}$, show that it is an entire function without zeroes. By Weierstrass factorization it can be written :
$$g(z) = e^{P(z)}$$
where $P$ is a polynomial. Prove the formula $g(z+1) = g(z)$ and deduce that $P$ must be of the form : $P(z) = a + 2 \pi i n z$ where $n$ is an integer. Then use the value of $g(1)$ and the fact that $g(z)$ takes real values for positive real $z$ to deduce : $a=n=0$ and conclude.
